# How to get the sum of specific rows

Tags: php, mysql

i am developing a blood bank management system. Now i want to display that how many times each user donated blood, i mean i want to get the sum of each user row. For example if a donor(who's passport/IC is AF3444547)has 3 row in the database so i need show the total row from the database.If next time i put another record of AF3444547 then i need to get the sum 4. The image shown in below of my databse. Thanks in advance 
[image: blood donation record]

**Here is my code**

```
 <?php
                    $passport_IC='passport_IC';
                      $q="SELECT passport_IC, count(*) FROM donate GROUP BY passport_IC";
                      $query=$db->prepare($q);

                      $query->execute(array($passport_IC));
                      $people = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);


                    ?>
     <table class="table table-bordered">
      <tr>
        <th><center> passport </center></th>
        <th><center> quantity</center></th>




      </tr>
      <?php foreach($people as $donors): ?>
        <tr>
           <td><center><b><font color="white"><?= $donors->passport_IC; ?></font></b></center></td>




        </tr>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: Use group by with count.

Comment: `SELECT count(*) as rows from donate WHERE passport_ic=:passport_ic`

Comment: could you please give me any example like this? it would be better for me to understand that how should i write the query @techgyyani

Comment: your code makes sense. it is not efficient (using count is better for efficiency) but is valid if you then want to display the report of each event... using count you just get the number of rows

Comment: where u bind `passport_ic` ?

Comment: My code is working but how i print the number of rows by count

Comment: @sayemali: answer updated

Answer (score 1):

Is not `sum()` what you need...

## `count(*)` is the answer.

> The COUNT (*) function returns the number of rows that satisfy the
>   WHERE clause of a SELECT statement.

https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1580.htm

```
 $q=$db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) from donate WHERE passport_ic=:passport_ic" );
```

Comment: Upvoted, but elaborate a little more on your answer. OP seems to be a little confused between counting returned rows and getting the result of aggregate functions.

Answer (score 0):

Please use:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total from donate WHERE passport_ic=:passport_ic
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [`rowCount`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) not `rowcount`

`$row=$q->rowcount();` should be `$del->rowCount()`

You can also achieve this by using your MYSQL Query, Use `count(*)` here to get total no of rows:

```
$q=$db->query("SELECT COUNT(*) as total from donate WHERE passport_ic=:passport_ic" );
```

Third, you can also use PHP `count()` method, which will return you count of your array as `echo count($q);`

---

**Edit:**

After updating your question, you have all rows in this array `$people`, so you can simple use `echo count($people);` this will return you total no of rows.

Comment: i used this one but nothing is showing ..even no error

Comment: @sayemali: where u bind `passport_ic` ?

Comment: @sayemali: share the result of `var_dump($row);`

Comment: @sayemali: or try with `echo count($q);` share the result

Comment: My code is working but how i print the number of rows by count @devpro

Comment: @sayemali: count with PHP, or MYSQL?