# what is the exact query to count specific rows from database

Tags: sql

From the database how to count specific rows. to clarify the image is given below.THANKS IN ADANCE. Expecting help.
[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kFLmo.png)

**HERE IS MY CODE**

```
              <?php
                        $q="SELECT * FROM donate WHERE 
                        passport_IC=:passport_IC";
                        $row=$q->rowcount(); 

                        echo $row;

                        ?>
```

Comment: this is the query you are looking for `SELECT passport_IC, count(*) FROM donate GROUP BY passport_IC`

Comment: Or, it you're literally just after the count `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM donate WHERE passport_IC=:password_IC`. (Note, won't work with rowcount, since only 1 row would be returned)

Comment: This is not a PHP question, although if that is your PHP you have multiple issues. (No query execution, no binding, no fetch)

Comment: How is this different from what you asked only three hours ago, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55609328/ ? - In general, IMHO you are asking stuff here that you should be learning on your own, by going through some beginner’s tutorials on the matter …

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the sum of specific rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55609328/how-to-get-the-sum-of-specific-rows)

Answer (score 0):

Via Mysql

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Table;
```

will count the number of rows in the table.

See the [reference manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html).

OR

Via PHP

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","db_name");
$result=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM Table")
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
  printf("Result set has %d rows.\n",$rowcount);
?>
```